# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'djoser' while running Django + Docker project

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, djoser

To add registration to django-project, I decided to use 'djoser' library. But while making migrations with
`docker-compose run server python manage.py makemigrations`
, the same error raises:

```
Creating school-co_server_run ... done
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/web/server/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/web/server/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'djoser'
ERROR: 1
```

The thing is that I already pip installed djoser (using the newest update of pip), I froze djoser too with the help of requirements.txt:

```
asgiref==3.2.10
attrs==21.2.0
Django==3.1
django-environ==0.8.1
django-extensions==3.1.5
django-filter==21.1
djangorestframework==3.12.4
djangorestframework-camel-case==1.2.0
drf-spectacular==0.21.0
inflection==0.5.1
jsonschema==4.2.1
Markdown==3.3.6
mysqlclient==2.1.0
Pillow==8.4.0
pyrsistent==0.18.0
pytz==2021.3
PyYAML==6.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
uritemplate==4.1.1
djoser==2.0.1
pandas=1.1.3
```

But it still doesn't work. Section of 'settings.py' INSTALLED_APPS also is correct:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'base',
    'school_co',
    'django_extensions',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'drf_spectacular',
    'djoser',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
]
```

I use docker-compose, and here is the `web/Dockerfile` in which the operation happens:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-bullseye

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN set -ex \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install curl default-libmysqlclient-dev gcc -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN useradd --create-home --shell /bin/bash --home /home/web web
USER web
WORKDIR /home/web

COPY etc/requirements.txt ./etc/requirements.txt

RUN set -ex \
    && python -m venv /home/web/venv \
    && ./venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip \
    && ./venv/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir -r ./etc/requirements.txt

COPY etc/env ./etc/env

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /home/web/venv
ENV PATH /home/web/venv/bin:$PATH
WORKDIR /home/web/server
```

Comment: show your `Dockerfile` and what command are you using when starting the container?

Comment: @Ersain, did it!

Comment: ok, did you rebuild the image after installing the `djoser`? (`docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`)

Comment: @Ersain, while running ```docker-compose build```, getting this:
```=> ERROR [6/8] RUN set -ex     && python -m venv /home/web/venv     && ./venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip      12.4s
------rs\daser\school-co>pip install pandas

 > [6/8] RUN set -ex     && python -m venv /home/web/venv     && ./venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip     && ./venv/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir -r ./etc/requirements.txt:ers\daser\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.19.2)```

Comment: @Ersain, oh, I found what was wrong, in the ```requirements.txt``` was `=` instead of `==` (pandas). I rebuilded the image, and now I am geting the new error: ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework_simplejwt'```

Comment: According to the `requirements.txt` there is no `djangorestframework-simplejwt` package, recheck the requirements, freeze them to `requirements.txt` and rebuild the image again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that 'djoser' doesn't work without 'pandas'.

That is why it is needed to add this library too. My mistake was that I accidentally typed '=' instead of '==' in `requirments.txt`.